# Array of strings - how to determine the number of elements present

Tags: string

I would like to use an array of strings which I define as follows:

```
char* CommandQueue[]={"FirstCommend", "SecondCommend", "ThirdCommand", "Cmd4", "Cmd5"};
```

The purpose of this array is to hold commands ("strings of various lengths") that the Arduino will receive through a serial port. Those commands will be interpreted by calling appropriate callback functions to act on them. The CommandQueue is supposed to line up the commands in a sort of "buffer".

Initially the "CommandQueue" array does not contain any elements and gets populated during the runtime of the project. The  array will continuously be interrogated and once a command is interpreted (and the corresponding function executed) the command will be eliminated from the queue.

How can I determine how many elements (i.e. strings) or commands are present in the array? The sizeof() function will not be helpful because the individual elements can be of different lengths.

Thanks in advance for your help or comments.

Comment: Just use a variable to store it... Which is the correct way to handle a buffer, i think...

Answer (score 2):

You can't know how many items are in an array simply because an array has a fixed size, and there is no such thing as "not an entry".

The closest you can have is a fixed size array and only some entries in it are valid - those that aren't valid have a special value to say "this is not a valid entry". For `char` pointers it's normal to use `NULL` as the "not a valid entry" value.

The drawback of this approach though is that you can never store more items than there are slots for, and finding out how many valid or invalid entries there are and shuffling them around when you remove the first entry is both a tedious and time consuming task.

Better in this situation to use a *circular buffer* which is a fixed size array but you remove the concept of a "first" entry. Instead you have a "head" and a "tail" value which is the locations in the array where you read from (remove the oldest) and write to (add after the newest).  It's how the serial port on the Arduino deals with incoming and outgoing data - as data arrives it is added to a circular buffer and you then read from that buffer.

To help work with circular buffers I wrote a small template class:

- https://github.com/MajenkoLibraries/CircularBuffer

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to know how long the command queue is, or just if there are still elements in it? This seems like a case where you might be better off using a different data structure – a linked list seems like an obvious possibility. If you're not familiar with linked lists, [this article](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/08/c-linked-list-example/) may be helpful. Otherwise, I think you'll need to keep track of the number of elements in the queue for yourself.

If you do use an array, it will need to be declared with a fixed length, something like:

```
 char * CommandQueue[MAX_QUEUE_LENGTH];
```

The `sizeof` operator would tell you the length of the array, but not the number of items in it (the length of the array is the number of character pointers defined by MAX_QUEUE_LENGTH). The code to manage the command queue as an array could get pretty messy, especially if you need to execute the commands in order.

If instead you use a linked list then each command is added to the list at the end as it comes in, and when you execute commands they are pulled from the head of the list. If you need to know the length of the queue you could either update it as you add and remove commands, or you could iterate over the list and count the number of items in the list.

Answer (score 1):

A very useful macro is [membersof](https://github.com/mikaelpatel/Cosa/blob/master/cores/cosa/Cosa/Types.h#L165)().

```
#define membersof(x) (sizeof(x) / sizeof(x[0]))
```

You will find in defined in large libraries and frameworks for C/C++. For your example above the number of elements is:

```
const int COMMAND_QUEUE_MAX = membersof(CommandQueue);
...
for (int i = 0; i < COMMAND_QUEUE_MAX; i++) ...
```

A dynamic set would require a max length and null terminated or simply a counter.

```
const int COMMAND_QUEUE_MAX = ...;
char* CommandQueue[COMMAND_QUEUE_MAX] = { ....., NULL };

for (char** cpp = CommandQueue; *cpp != NULL; cpp++) {
  char* name = *cp;
  ...
}
```

Or even better use a [Queue](https://github.com/mikaelpatel/Cosa/blob/master/cores/cosa/Cosa/Queue.hh) data type:

```
Queue<char*, COMMAND_QUEUE_MAX> CommandQueue;
...
char* cp;
while (CommandQueue.dequeue(&cp)) ...
```

Cheers!